# OpenLDAP: Converting flat file (slapd.conf) to OLC (slapd.d)...can't access cn=config

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

I'm attempting to set up OpenLDAP.  I was having trouble with the OLC config option, so I went with the slapd.conf style input as I'm a complete noob at LDAP and it was easier to understand.

I now have a need to use the OLC config option, so I'm trying to convert.  I'm able to convert correctly using the command

```
slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d
chown ldap:ldap -R /etc/openldap/slapd.d
```

and everything starts and works correctly and everything is hunky dory.  However, I can't seem to access `cn=config` using ldapsearch.  I've tried anonymous access with:

```
ldapsearch -x -D -b 'cn=config' '(objectclass=*)'
```

which returns `32 No such object`

I would love any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's my (now obsolete and converted) slapd.conf file:

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema

pidfile         /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile        /var/run/openldap/slapd.args

moduleload memberof.so

access to dn.base="" by * read
access to dn.base="cn=Subschema" by * read
access to dn.base="ou=users,dc=example,dc=com" filter=(objectclass=organizationalUnit)
        by dn.subtree="ou=sysusers,dc=example,dc=com" read
        by users read
access to dn.children="ou=users,dc=example,dc=com" filter=(objectclass=inetOrgPerson) attrs=uid,memberOf,entry,objectClass
        by dn.subtree="ou=sysusers,dc=example,dc=com" read
        by self write
access to dn.children="ou=users,dc=example,dc=com" filter=(objectclass=inetOrgPerson) attrs=mail,cn
        by dn.base="cn=owncloud,ou=sysusers,dc=example,dc=com" read
        by self write
access to dn.base="dc=example,dc=com"
        by users read
access to *
        by self write
        by anonymous auth

database        hdb
suffix          "dc=example,dc=com"
checkpoint      32      30
rootdn          "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
rootpw          {SSHA}redactedredactedredacted
directory       /var/lib/openldap-data
index   objectClass     eq
loglevel 4

overlay memberof

database config
access to *
    by dn.exact="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage
    by * read
```

I am brand new at setting up an ldap server, so sorry if I ask stupid questions.

Comment: Does the 'peercred' rule work? (That is, does `ldapsearch -H ldapi:// -Y EXTERNAL` have access?) What does `slapacl -b cn=config entry/read` show?

Comment: `ldapsearch -H lapi:// -Y EXTERNAL -x -b 'cn=config' '(objectclass=*)'` returns "ldapsearch: incompatible with previous authentication choice".  `slapacl -b cn=config entry/read` gives me "slapacl: target database doesn't support necessary operations; you may try with "-u" (dry run).  Adding `-u` gives me "read access to entry: DENIED"

Comment: Oh i just realized that -x and -Y are conflicting.  Removing the -x from the ldapsearch command gives me, again, "32 No such object"

Comment: Forgot to mention – do the search as root (since the ACL says uid 0).

Comment: Yup, all commands were run as root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, attempting to use slaptest to generate your slapd.d directory when it is already full of stuff doesn't generate a new one.  My example slapd.conf posted above wasn't actually being converted into slapd.d.

Once I deleted slapd.d and ran everything again, things were hunky dory.